# Why is $M_n(k)$ a semisimple $M_n(k)$-module?

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, semi-simple-rings

I found in my notes that, for $k$ a field,

> $M_n(k)$ is a direct sum of its column left ideals, so it is a semisimple $M_n(k)$-module.

I don't understand the first clause, though I feel it must be some obvious linear algebra.

I mean, what are the column left ideals of $M_n(k)$?

I think of the spaces generated by each element of the canonical basis for $M_n(k)$, i.e. The matrices with a 1-entry and all the other entries zero, but they're not *column* ideals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do $n=2$. The column left ideals in this case are
$$I_1=\left\{\pmatrix{*&0\\*&0}\right\}$$
and
$$I_2=\left\{\pmatrix{0&*\\0&*}\right\}$$
in what I hope is an obvious notation. Then $M_2(k)=I_1\oplus I_2$
and moreover $I_1=M_2(k)A$ for any nonzero $A\in I_1$ (and similarly for
$I_2$) so that $I_1$ is a simple module etc.

Comment: Oh thanks, now that it is written out it's clearer. And that's also a nice way to see the simplicity of $I_1$.